# How did Wanda know which universe to dreamwalk into?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness, scarlet-witch

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Wanda Maximoff (or the Scarlet Witch) uses dreamwalking to try and capture America Chavez after she and Stephen Strange leave the main Marvel universe. However, when she is in a web of the different universes, she is only looking at images of *herself* and her *children*, not Doctor Strange and America Chavez. How did she know to dreamwalk into 838 and not some random other universe without seeing images of America and Strange?

Comment: I am guessing… *magic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### By using the Darkhold

Even without possessing a body in another universe, Wanda / the Scarlet Witch can use the Darkhold to peer into other universes. It's how she learned where her sons are in the first place, and how she is tracking America Chavez. In the post-credits scene of *WandaVision* S01E09 "The Series Finale", while studying the Darkhold in her astral form (and presumably searching for her sons), Wanda hears her sons calling for help.

[image: Relevant section of Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline (text quoted below)]

> ##### Fall 2023 | Darkhold Corruption
>
> In a remote cabin, Wanda Maximoff studies the pages of the Darkhold that she took from Agatha Harkness. Its pages contain forbidden methods of traversing universes, and with He Who Remains now gone, and the TVA no longer maintaining the Sacred Timeline, the doorways are open. Wanda uses the Darkhold to pinpoint alternate realities where her sons Tommy and Billy still exist. Reaching them is still beyond her abilities, however, so she will need to find another with the power to puncture the barrier between realities.

- [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)

[image: WandaVision S01E09 screencap][image: Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness screencap]

The first screencap is from *WandaVision* S01E09, where she learns that her sons are alive, while the second screencap is from *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, where she learns that Earth-616 Strange and Chavez are in Earth-838. Notice the similarities in the scene compositions.

When *WandaVision* S01E09 was released, the audience hasn't yet learned of the multiverse, variants, dreamwalking, and such (*Loki* Season 1 wasn't released yet). Wanda learned that her sons were alive *somewhere*. In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* it was revealed that *somewhere* was in another universe and that Wanda has found them. From that, we can infer that she can search for people in other universes using the Darkhold. It's also how she learned of America Chavez and her unique ability. Wanda was able to track Chavez in multiple universes and send multiple creatures after her, even in the gap junction (the space between universes).

Illuminati Strange and Sinister Strange also peer into other universes using their versions of the Darkhold.

> **Mordo:** He turned to the Darkhold... Began dreamwalking... In hopes that our salvation might lie in the multiverse.
> **Captain Marvel:** And guess what? It didn't. But he kept doing it anyway.

> **Sinister Strange:** I was looking for a world where things were different. Where I had
> Christine, where I was happy. But I didn't find it. All I found were more of us.

Comment: Wanda's sons were the offspring of her own variants, so her ability to locate them is explained by Dreamwalking, as is Sinister Strange searching for a universe where he and Christine remained together. None of that explains how Wanda knew that America Chavez and 616-Strange were in Universe-838, or that they were to be found in the Illuminati's headquarters, specifically. We know Wanda could look directly into the home of her 838 counterpart, but we never saw her surveilling an area in another universe where one of her variants was verifiably not present.

Comment: @LogicDictates I believe she doesn't need to be dreamwalking to peer into other universes. She was able to track Chavez in multiple universes even before Chavez went to Earth-838. Chavez didn't even know (hasn't met) Wanda or her variants until Earth-616 Strange told her about Wanda. In *WandaVision*, Wanda wasn't shown to be dreamwalking when she heard her sons.

Comment: We see Wanda using a Darkhold spell to peer into other universes, but she's only shown viewing her own variants and their sons, and on two occasions where she does this, she Dreamwalks in the same scene, suggesting it may be part of the same spell, or a related spell. It's not clear that she can look at anything or anyone she wants to in other universes, and even if she can, how does she know which universe to look at, and which location within that universe? Each individual Earth is a big place and she apparently didn't know Chavez was in Kamar-Taj, until Strange told her.

Comment: Wanda sent creatures after Chavez in other universes before meeting her, but it's unclear whether she herself knew which locations in which universes to send the creatures to, or whether the creatures were able to track Chavez on their own. It's also unclear whether she herself transported the creatures between universes, or whether they were able to do that on their own. It seems incongruous that she could transport those creatures between universes, but not her own physical body.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I don't think it was ever explained how Wanda knew about Chavez and her powers in the first place. Was Chavez specifically mentioned in the Darkhold, or did Wanda learn of her by chance while Dreamwalking or peering into other universes? That may be worthy of a separate question in itself.

Comment: @LogicDictates "[...] she apparently didn't know Chavez was in Kamar-Taj, until Strange told her." I believe Wanda was bluffing here. She knew exactly where Chavez was and was trying to get Strange to bring Chavez to her.

Comment: What evidence is there that Wanda knew Chavez was in Kamar-Taj before Strange told her? Also, how did Wanda know in advance that Strange would approach her for help?

Comment: @LogicDictates There is no direct evidence in the film whether or not Wanda knew Chavez was in Kamar-Taj. I'm inferring Wanda knew based on the fact that she has tracked Chavez in at least 3 universes prior to Strange approaching her. Tracking Chavez in Earth-616 should not be a problem for a Darkhold user. Wanda *knew* Strange would come to her. She prepared her hex illusion and bluff well in advance of Strange approaching her. "You know, the hex was the easy part. The lying, not so much."

Comment: @LogicDictates "*How did Wanda know in advance that Strange would approach her for help?*" Wanda was tracking Chavez, and by extension, Strange. Wanda knew that she is the obvious choice to deal with the Chavez situation. "This isn't sorcery. It's witchcraft." "Do we know anyone who's faced such a thing?" "I think I might." "But given the choice between the Archer with the mohawk and several bug-themed crime fighters. Or one of the most powerful magic-wielders on the planet, it's an easy call."

Comment: "Magic takes care of it" seems the obvious answer

Comment: @LogicDictates Just the fact that Wanda sent minions after Chavez throughout the multiverse and knew Chavez, a person who is supposed to have no other variants, by name without being told, means she had insight into other universes that weren't explicitly depicted on screen. She knew her kids existed elsewhere because she dreamed of them. Throw magic into the equation (heh) and you end up with a lot of implicit options.

Comment: @Digital Jedi - _"Just the fact that Wanda sent minions after Chavez throughout the multiverse and knew Chavez, a person who is supposed to have no other variants, by name without being told, means she had insight into other universes that weren't explicitly depicted on screen."_ Sure, but the notion that Wanda can peer into parts of other universes where one of her variants isn't present doesn't seem to be directly supported by any evidence from an official source. It's a solid theory, but nothing more than that until better evidence comes along.

Comment: @LogicDictates Implicit information is a thing in movies, without having to be confirmed. Strange took a bus or a train or a portal or a car to Christine's wedding. You know this because he is one place, and then he's in another. You don't need confirmation that he used one of those means, just that they're the only way possible to get there.