# How did Wanda learn of America Chavez and her powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness, scarlet-witch

It's been a few months since I watched *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* in full, so forgive me if I've forgotten something important here, but I don't think it was ever explained how Wanda initially learned of America Chavez and her powers.

To clarify, I'm not looking for a vague answer like "magic" or the "the Darkhold", but something more specific. Like, was Chavez mentioned within the Darkhold itself, or did Wanda learn of her by chance while Dreamwalking, or through some other means?

I'm also not looking for theories, but rather a canon explanation provided either by the movie itself, or some other official source. If no clear explanation has been provided, that in itself is a legitimate answer, but you'd need to have researched the subject pretty extensively to be sure of that.

Comment: Wanda's been looking into the multiverse to find one she can get her kids in and then also looking for a way to get to them. We're not shown exactly how the windows into other universes work but if she's looking for a way to travel the multiverse it's conceivable this spell helped locate America even if Wanda didn't know exactly what she was looking for.

Comment: Also side note: that article isn't much more than a rant and the fact it calls this a plot hole when it's not (which is a pet peeve of mine) doesn't help itself out too much.

Comment: While not strictly qualifying as a plot hole, it is an important plot point that should've (and easily could've) been clarified within the film. I think there're quite a few significant plot points that weren't explained, and it leaves me wondering how carefully the writers have thought this stuff through, and whether or not they expect the audience not to notice these gaps in the narrative.

Comment: Something not being explained is not a plot hole just something that isn’t explained for good or bad. There’s only so much that can fit in the film after all and they evidently chose to leave this out believing it isn’t necessarily that important to the story of the film they wanted to tell. Wanda knowing of America is really all that matters for the context of the film.

Comment: The plot of this film relies heavily on certain rules, stated or implied, like Wanda not being able to transport her physical form between universes, and seemingly not being able to view anything she wants in other universes. Establishing how Wanda knew about Chavez is important to show that the writers didn't break their own rules, and it could've been done with a single line of dialogue, or a brief shot of a page within the Darkhold.

Comment: Wanda wouldn't have read the Book of Vishanti since she's corrupted by the Darkhold. By process of elimination, I believe the answer is: the Darkhold; or its author, Chthon. Related: [How did Wanda know which universe to dreamwalk into?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/266069/7957)

Comment: I'm not sure we need a long ranty review to support your premise.

Answer (score 9):

America, or at least someone with America's powers i.e. a multiversal traveller, appears to be mentioned in the Book of Vishanti. We see a star shape similar to her portal shapes on one of the pages when Wanda destroys it:

[image: The Book of Vishanti on the floor burning with red fire magic; a star shape is visible on the page]

Apart from that there isn't any mention of her that I know of in the film. Presumably though either she is also mentioned directly in the Darkhold as the two books are opposites. Or Wanda found out information about her whilst looking for a way to travel the multiverse to be with "her kids". Whether that was accidental, some other means or through some sort of spell whilst she was peering into the multiverse.

Remember how when Stephen peers into the multiverse he gets shown America, it's possible Wanda was too: sort of like a thing you want the most or thing you are looking for. If that's the case then Wanda just looking into the multiverse for something to help her travel it would probably show her America.

However, all that being said I am aware of no direct, explicit answer to this question either in the film or out of it at the moment and if it wasn't for the Book of Vishanti information I would have left this as a comment. That together with common sense though seems to hold the key for how Wanda found out about America.

I will say she could have found out about her from the Book of Vishanti herself but I'm not overly sure on this. She'd been to the Gap Junction multiple times via proxy that we saw. It is entirely possible she also went there, herself or via proxy, to read the Book of Vishanti but I don't think she'd have left it there given her attitude in the film: she would either have destroyed it or taken it with her.

Comment: +1 The idea that Chavez was mentioned within the Darkhold is the most plausible explanation that occurred to me, and while this answer doesn't strictly confirm that, it does lend credence to it as a strong possibility. I have a hard time believing that an entity like the Ribboned Creature (that was chasing Defender Strange and Chavez through the Gap Junction at the start of the film) would've read the Book of Vishanti on Wanda's behalf, though.

Comment: Presumably, the Darkhold mentions all or notable inter-dimensional beings (possibly with notable powers, including America Chavez) as Scarlet Witch uses Darkhold to summon inter-dimensional beings also.

Comment: @LogicDictates to be clear I didn’t necessarily mean the Ribboned Creature; she could have used anything to do that. But I do think it’s an unlikely scenario as I mentioned above.

Comment: @ermanen - It makes sense that an ancient book of black magic would contain entries on ancient and evil/monstrous entities. It's not as obvious that it'd contain an entry on a teenage superhero from the present day. Thinking about it, it makes more sense that she'd be mentioned in the Book of Vishanti, the white magic counterpart of the Darkhold, rather than the Darkhold itself. I don't think there's supposed to be a lot of overlap in terms of what's covered in each book.

Comment: Scarlet Witch only had the Darkhold so I only mentioned the Darkhold. Possibly both books mention America Chavez. Possibly not directly. (maybe the race with this power or a way to find these kind of beings) She is a unique being with a unique power with no multiversal variants.

Comment: @LogicDictates: I suspect that ermanen's comment may be correct - it may also just say that "The way to find someone who can multiversal travel is if they have no multiversal variants."; at that point, it can become a multi-verse game of Guess Who.